# Divide square into congruent isosceles triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

Can I divide a square using other congruent isosceles triangles than $45-90-45$ ones? For example, can I use $30-120-30$ congruent triangles to completely cover a square without overlapping or extending outside the square?

My single argument so for is that the corner of the square must be composed only of one type of angle(isosceles triangles have two "types" of them: 2 at the base and one at top). That comes from the fact that $2a + b = 180; a, b > 0; a + b < 90 => a > 90$ (impossible). Also the chosen angle that is chosen for completing the corner must divide 90 exactly. Namely $90/a = i$, where $i$ is an positive integer.

Comment: Say it's the unit square.  When you tile it with triangles the sides of the square are divided into segments equal to sides of the triangle, so I think the triangle sides will probably all have to be rational.  Of course, the area has to be the reciprocal of an integer.

Comment: The actual side of the square is irrelevant as far as I can tell. I don't see why you couldn't compose the side of the square from both the legs and base of the triangles with which you are tiling. I mean I don't see neither arguments for or against having the sides of the square composed only from the base or the legs. My single argument so for is that the corner of the square must be composed only of one type of angle(isosceles triangles have two "types" of them: 2 at the base and one at top).

Comment: The side lengths are not irrelevant if you assume, without loss of generality, that the square you are tiling has side $1$.  As to the other statement, I haven't worked it out, it's just a thought suggested by a similar problem I worked on once.

Comment: Please put any thoughts you have about the problem into the body of the question, not the comments.

Comment: I've a feeling it will be useful to have a think about the dihedral group $D_4$ and how the symmetries of the tiling will behave under those symmetries. For example, ask how many ways some chosen triangle can fit into a corner, then think about opposing corners look and how that impacts the tiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done with $30^\circ$-$30^\circ$-$120^\circ$ triangles.  Suppose the unit square is tiled with $n$ such triangles, whose equal sides have length $s$ and whose longest sides have length $t=\sqrt{3}s.$  The area of each triangle is $$\frac12 s^2\sin{120^\circ}={s^2\sqrt{3}\over4}=\frac1n,$$ so that $$\frac1s={\sqrt{n}\sqrt[4]{3}\over2},$$ an algebraic number of degree $4$.

On the other hand, the tiling divides each side of the square into line segments of lengths $s$ and $t$. Suppose one side is covered by $a$ segments of length $s$ and $b$ segments of length $t$ where $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers, not both $0$.  Then we have $$as+bt=1\implies as+b\sqrt{3}s=1$$ so that $$\frac1s=a+b\sqrt{3}$$ an algebraic number of degree $2$, contradicting the earlier result.

It should be possible to extend this line of reasoning to solve the general problem, but I don't think I remember enough algebra.